# Infinite loop triggered when calling child state in UI-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nested, angular-ui-router, state

I have the following config in a parent controller in UI-Router.

```
$stateProvider.state('store', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/:store',
    resolve: {
        Store : ['StoreService', '$stateParams', '$state', '$rootScope', function (StoreService, $stateParams, $state, $rootScope) {

            return StoreService.getStoreByCode($stateParams.store).then(
                function (response){
                    $rootScope.Store = response.data; 
                    return response.data;
                },
                function (response){
                    $state.go('store.404', $stateParams);
                }
            );
        }]
    },
    templateUrl: 'app/app.html'
});
```

Then in  a child config I have:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('store.404', {
        parent:'store',
        url: '/store.404',
        template: '<h1>Whoa! 404!</h1>'
    });
```

The problem is that when the promise in the resolve statement is rejected, the `$state.go('store.404')` triggers and infinite loop and crashes the browser.

Is this because the parent is loading and resolving every time it tries to go to that child state? Is there a clean way to not have that resolve statement trigger on the child state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *...Is this because the parent is loading and resolving every time it tries to go to that child state?*

Yes.

> *...Is there a clean way to not have that resolve statement trigger on the child state?*

No

Solution is - state like '404' should be separate, special one. Such, which will be available always, without any restrictions or error handling.

I.e. - move '404' state outside of any parent.